# WARNING: Unexpected type for now playing key kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoDuration

Tags: ios, swift

I'm seeing the following error in my console.

```
WARNING: Unexpected type for now playing key kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoDuration (is CFType, should be CFNumber). Removing from now playing info dictionary.
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
if let duration = player.currentItem?.asset.duration {
   nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = duration
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same problem and fixed it Find the below solution: you have forgotten to mention".seconds"

```
if let currentItem = player.currentItem {
     let duration = currentItem.asset.duration
      nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = duration.seconds


}
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/controlling_background_audio